# How do I draw a caret on an image?

Tags: c#

In my application the user can write from keyboard on an image. Is it possible to display the caret on the image (as in `TextBox` for example)?

Comment: what do you mean ? How can one *write* on image something? Do you mean *drawing* characters on the image surface ?

Comment: Yes, I meant caret. And drawing characters on image surface

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got 3 separate issues:

1) Drawing Text at arbitrary locations.
See [MSDN DrawString Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.drawstring.aspx)

2) Merging two separate images (the original and the text) into one.
As far as I know the image host controls, that you're likely using to show the image, provide a bitmap object property, so you need to be able to save that bitmap object to a file once you've done the DrawString.

3) Draw the caret symbol at arbitrary locations
You can do this with basic drawing commands to create your own caret, that's using Graphics with Pens and Paths.
Then the issue is to make it flash (which means drawing what's underneath your caret again, then your caret etc)
I *think* there's options on the Pen object that might achieve this for you.

I would tackle each in turn then put them together.

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to the Caret (the blinking indicator which shows the position when inputting text), you probably have to use P/Invoke. You should start here:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff468799(v=vs.85).aspx